# how to select distinct children in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

got this query

```
    "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "has_parent": {
                            "parent_type": "profiles",
                            "query": {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "query": "age:>0 and user:aqwe"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "sort": ["user", {"createdAt": "asc"}]
```

as a result got multiple items with same '_id', I think this is something like problem with joining. How to edit this query to select distinct items?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return only unique values you can use terms aggregation. In your case it would look like this (size in this case is maximum number of unique ids you want to return):

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": {
            "has_parent": {
                "parent_type": "profiles",
                "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "age:>0 and user:aqwe"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "unique": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "_id",
            "size": 100
        }
    }
}    
"sort": ["user", {"createdAt": "asc"}]
```

Comment: You could use ?routing=idofoneparent if you know it to target the child you want. And so maybe build a more complex querry. Note this is not a bug childs received parents _id as routing value, so the id of a child contains also his parent one.